# How to pass one query result to multiple queries as parameter in same table and get all columns in single row in sql

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    Subjects, Sec1, Sec2, Sec3, Sec4, Sec5, Sec6, Sec7, Sec8 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT SubjectId AS Subjects 
     FROM Feedback 
     WHERE StudentId LIKE '%BIT%' AND Sem='8') q1,
    (SELECT SUM(StarValue) AS Sec1 
     FROM Feedback 
     WHERE StudentId LIKE '%BIT%' AND Sem = '8' AND QuestionId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) q2,
    (SELECT SUM(StarValue) AS Sec2 
     FROM Feedback 
     WHERE StudentId LIKE '%BIT%' AND Sem = '8' AND QuestionId IN (7, 8, 9)) q3,
    (SELECT SUM(StarValue) AS Sec3 
     FROM Feedback 
     WHERE StudentId LIKE '%BIT%' AND Sem = '8' AND QuestionId IN (10)) q4,
    (SELECT SUM(StarValue) AS Sec4 
     FROM Feedback 
     WHERE StudentId LIKE '%BIT%' AND Sem = '8' AND QuestionId IN (11)) q5,
    (SELECT SUM(StarValue) AS Sec5 
     FROM Feedback 
     WHERE StudentId LIKE '%BIT%' AND Sem = '8' AND QuestionId IN (12, 13)) q6,
    (SELECT SUM(StarValue) AS Sec6 
     FROM Feedback 
     WHERE StudentId LIKE '%BIT%' AND Sem = '8' AND QuestionId IN (14)) q7,
    (SELECT SUM(StarValue) AS Sec7 
     FROM Feedback 
     WHERE StudentId LIKE '%BIT%' AND Sem = '8' AND QuestionId IN (15)) q8,
    (SELECT SUM(StarValue) AS Sec8 
     FROM Feedback 
     WHERE StudentId LIKE '%BIT%' AND Sem = '8' AND QuestionId IN (16, 17, 18, 19, 20)) q9
```

Here, I want to calculate sum of `starvalue` to each subject in particular department and semester. But, I don't know how to pass `subjectid` taken from above query(q1).

The schema of `Feedback` table is:

```
StudentId varchar(50)
Sem int
SubjectId varchar(50)
QuestionId int
StarValue int
Date datetime
```

The below query will execute result for sec1 but I don't know how to execute another sections queries and combine the result as single row.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SubjectId, SUM(StarValue) AS Sec1 
FROM Feedback 
WHERE (1 = 1) 
  AND StudentId LIKE '%BIT%' 
  AND Sem = '8' 
  AND QuestionId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
GROUP BY SubjectId
```

This is the exact result for section1. I want output for other sections like these to each subject according to its department and semester:

[image: It is the exact result for section1. i want output for another sections like these to each subject according to it's department and semester]

[image: This is the above code capture]

Answer (score 1):

You could just apply the predicate to filter questions within the aggregate function, and do this with a single table read:

```
SELECT  SubjectID,
        Sec1 = SUM(CASE WHEN QuestionID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) THEN StarValue END),
        Sec2 = SUM(CASE WHEN QuestionID IN (7, 8, 9) THEN StarValue END),
        Sec3 = SUM(CASE WHEN QuestionID IN (10) THEN StarValue END),
        Sec4 = SUM(CASE WHEN QuestionID IN (11) THEN StarValue END),
        Sec5 = SUM(CASE WHEN QuestionID IN (12, 13) THEN StarValue END),
        Sec6 = SUM(CASE WHEN QuestionID IN (14) THEN StarValue END),
        Sec7 = SUM(CASE WHEN QuestionID IN (15) THEN StarValue END),
        Sec8 = SUM(CASE WHEN QuestionID IN (16, 17, 18, 19, 20) THEN StarValue END)
FROM    Feedback
WHERE   StudentID LIKE '%BIT%'
AND     Sem = '8'
GROUP BY SubjectID;
```